# Unable to cascade delete a @OneToOne member

Tags: sql, mysql, hibernate, jpa, h2

```
@Entity public class Organization {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @Cascade(value = DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Days days;

}
```

I have the following entity definition and it generates a SQL to do a cascade delete on the @OneToOne entry when the parent object gets deleted. But it's not removing the "days" entry while deleting an Organization.

This happens with h2, mysql databases, what could be the problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My query looks like this "delete from Organization where some_key_id = ?" (am not deleting this based on primary key id)

A bulk delete (you should mention that in your question) doesn't cascade to anything. Quoting the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations
>
> ...
>
> A delete operation only applies to
>   entities of the specified class and
>   its subclasses. **It does not cascade to
>   related entities**.

This is a very annoying limitation and there are many RFEs to improve things ([HHH-695](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-695), [HHH-1917](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1917), [HHH-3337](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3337), [HHH-5529](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5529), etc).

For now, possible solutions include:

1. clean up the child table yourself
2. use cascading foreign keys in the schema.

Now the weird part... My understanding of `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` is that this annotation is supposed to be used to ensure that the foreign key is created with the appropriate `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause (solution #2). In other words, I'd expect things to work.

Did Hibernate generate the `Organization` table? Can you check the DDL? Do you see the expected `ON DELETE CASCADE`? If not, add it.

Comment: The weird part is "on delete cascade" is automatically added as a constraint, but it is not getting honoured in certain cases.

Comment: After some more investigation, I found that "on delete cascade" is effective when I just delete the parent (e.g. if it's a single level), but if the parent itself is contained as @OneToMany in a super parent this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Samuel It looks like a pure database/H2/MySQL question now. This goes beyond my expertise. My suggestion would be to ask a "database oriented" question (with simplified tables illustrating your context) to get answers from database experts and see if this is expected or not.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I guess you should add a

```
@Cascade(value = {DELETE, DELETE_ORPHAN})
```

Note that in JPA 2.0 you don't have to use the hibernate-sepcific `@Cascade` annotation - `@*ToMany` has an option to delete orphans.

**Update:** when using queries cascades are *not* handled. You have to handle them manually. This is expected and documented behaviour.

Comment: adding DELETE didn't help me and we are not in JPA2.0 yet

Comment: My query looks like this "delete from Organization where some_key_id = ?" (am not deleting this based on primary key id)

Comment: @Samuel, well then you have to handle the delete manually. See my update.